# How to sort data tables using the header row by alphabetical order

Tags: php, sql, sorting

Im doing a sch project and I need help in sorting my data table in alphabetical order by clicking the header row. Im using MySQL and I intend to use a php to implement it. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

This is my code:

This is a php file.

```
<?php


  @ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'f33s01', 'f33s01', 'f33s01');

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     echo 'Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.';
     exit;
  }

  $query = "select * from gyms";
  $result = $db->query($query);

  $num_results = $result->num_rows;


  echo "<table border=\"3\" cellpadding=\"5\" class=\"dirtable\" style=\"margin-bottom:15px\">
        <tr align=\"center\" class=\"gold\">
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Gym Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th width=\"18%\">Operating Hours</th>
        <th>Reservation</th>
        </tr>";

  for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++) {
     $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td align=\"center\">".($i+1)."</td>";
     echo  "<td align=\"center\">".stripslashes($row['gymname'])."</td>";
     echo "<td>".stripslashes($row['address'])."</td>";
     echo  "<td>".stripslashes($row['location'])."</td>";
     echo  "<td align=\"center\">".stripslashes($row['operatinghours'])."</td>";
     echo  "<td align=\"center\"><input type= \"submit\" value=\"BOOK NOW\" class=\"bookbutton\"></td>";     
     echo "</td>";   
     echo "</tr>";

  }


      echo "</table>";    
      echo "</form>";


  $result->free();
  $db->close();

?>
```

Comment: You may use jquery datatables plugin for this purpose.

Comment: Why do you have `stripslashes`? Is the data escaped inside the table? You canuse something like `htmlspecialchars` to escape potential HTML-code coming from the database.

Answer (score 0):

To strictly answer your question, you can use links in the column headings to pass $_GET variables to your page, and customize your mysql queries with SORT BY in order to render the data. I'll give a rough outline, this should get you pointed in the right direction. You will need to add in more logic on the heading urls to enable sorting in multiple directions.

For the heading:

```
echo "<th><a href='".$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]."?orderby=gymname&order=desc'>Gym Name</a>";
```

And then before your mysql code, have a switch statement

```
switch($_GET[orderby]) {
    case "gymname":
        $filter_orderby = "gymname";
        break;
    case "address":
        $filter_orderby = "address";
        break;
    //...other cases...
}
switch($_GET[order]) {
    case "desc":
        $filter_order = "DESC";
        break;
    case "asc":
        $filter_order = "ASC";
        break;
}
```

Now, you can append those to your query:

```
$myquery = "SELECT * FROM gyms WHERE 1 = 1";
if(isset($filter_orderby) {
    $myquery .= " ORDER BY ".$filter_orderby." ".$filter_order;
}
//Result: SELECT * FROM gyms WHERE 1 = 1 ORDER BY gymname DESC
```

If this data is not paginated or otherwise in a non-flat presentation then I would agree with Nikita Singh's suggestion of using a jQuery plugin - another is http://tablesorter.com/